# Some packages listed as updates by Ubuntu Software centre, but not by `sudo apt update`. Why?

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

I'm fairly *new* to Ubuntu. I read a couple dozen articles to understand the basic functionality and the overall use(how-tos etc.).
I read and I know that I can update whatever packages I have installed by the command `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade`. I also know that the software centre is *kind of* in-the-works and doesn't show the updates for all the packages. So I was upgrading my packages with the help of command-line.

Today a pop-up came which said I have some updates, clicking on it opened the Ubuntu software centre with two packages showing in the updates tab. Now, when I run `sudo apt update`, it shows `All packages are up to date`. Let's just say that I avoid using Ubuntu Software centre and I'm not really fond of it. **Why aren't those two packages listed with the `sudo apt update` command and how can I upgrade them using the command line?**

I'm attaching some screenshots for better understanding:

[image]

[image]

**PS**: I actually solved this question just before posting. But for some sake, I decided to post this anyways. See the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was flatpak. A simple `flatpak update` did the trick.
This is because flatpak apps aren't updated automatically unlike snaps. And this command
`flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`
when setting up flatpak added the repo to Ubuntu software centre, so that is why the updates were showing there. And since these are flatpaks(meaning they aren't from the Ubuntu official or community-maintained repositories), these packages did not show up in `sudo apt update`.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting. (also for the pic in the question)

Comment: I'll keep that in my mind next time @muru